# SSDT Publish Script Differs from Schema Compare Script

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I'm beginning to use the SSDT tools in Visual Studio 2013.  I've been using SSMS for 2008-R2.  I've created my project from an existing SQL Server database and have made some changes to stored procedures and have dropped a few tables in my project.  I've been trying to publish these changes to the database.

First, I've told the project to publish the changes straight to the server, which resulted in no changes in the actual database.  I then told it to generate the script instead, however the script that was created contains no changes:

```
GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];

GO
PRINT N'Update complete.';

GO
```

I then used the schema compare to compare the project to the database and told it to generate the script.  All the changes were found and the script created has the changes in there.

Can anyone tell me why the schema compare and publish scripts would differ and why publish is not recognizing the changes?

Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: I believe I figured it out.  When in the publishing wizard head, click the Advanced button-> Drop Tab -> Check the "Drop objects in target bu not in source"

Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f898d18-7283-429e-a723-2f63f900b340/drop-a-table-in-ssdt-without-writing-script?forum=ssdt

Comment: In general, you'll want to make sure you have the same options checked when doing Publish vs. Compare actions. Sounds like you found the source of your problem, though.